# C# stack overflow state

Tags: c#

In my base class, the one that the others inherit from, has these properties:

```
private int DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ORDER = 999999;
private DateTime DEFAULT_DT = new DateTime(1111,1,1);

public int? Id {
    get 
    { 
        return Id.GetValueOrDefault(0);  
    }
    set 
    {
        if (DisplayOrder == null) DisplayOrder = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ORDER;
        Id = value;
    }
}
public String Description { get; set; }
public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
```

But when I execute it, I get this error:

```
+ $exception {
     Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack 
     overflow state.}
     System.Exception {System.StackOverflowException}
```

on line

```
if (DisplayOrder == null) DisplayOrder = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ORDER;
```

What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this:

```
public int? Id {
    get 
    { 
        return Id.GetValueOrDefault(0);  
    }
```

Here, accessing `Id` requires that you first fetch... `Id`. Bang.

Next:

```
set 
{
    if (DisplayOrder == null) DisplayOrder = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ORDER;
    Id = value;
}
```

Look at the second part. In order to set `Id`, you have to... call the setter for `Id`. Bang.

You need a field for this:

```
private int? id;

// Now use the field in the property bodies
public int? Id {
    get 
    { 
        return id.GetValueOrDefault(0);  
    }
    set 
    {
        if (DisplayOrder == null) DisplayOrder = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ORDER;
        id = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling Id from within itself - infinitely recursive... not good :)

```
public int? Id {
    get 
    { 
        return Id.GetValueOrDefault(0); // This will keep calling the getter of Id. You need a backing field instead.
    }
    set 
    {
        if (DisplayOrder == null) DisplayOrder = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ORDER;
        Id = value; // And here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ID = value` will set off a loop. You should have a private variable like `_id` and use it in the setter and getter portions of the property.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a infinite loop, because you are referring to Id property in get and set of the Id property :P. So in get, you are getting to get the getting ;). And in the set, you are setting to set the setting. Weird huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Id = value;
```

This does. You are doing recursive assignment to property inside the same property.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Id, it calls Id again recursively over and over.

```
return Id.GetValueOrDefault(0);
```